# If flame sensor will affect Motor assembly's functionality of furnace? How does that work?

Tags: air-conditioning, furnace

I have two Air conditioning company. A is the self-hired for my A/C, and B is assigned by home warranty company.

This summer, the technician with A came out for an annual maintenance on both A/C and Furnace. He stated on the report: "FOUND CRACK IN INDUCER MOTOR HOUSING. MOTOR ASSEMBLY SHOULD BE REPLACED BEFORE 
FURNACE IS STARTED TO AVOID POSSIBLE CO POISIONING."

Then, I contacted B check out the furnace couple days ago. The technician with B stated "No worry, you will be easily smell it if there is any CO or gas leak. I don't smell anything. Flame sensor is too dirty that's what cause the issue "

But I am confused... what does that to do with the Motor assembly... and how does motor assembly work?

Comment: You **CANNOT** smell a CO leak. CO is a odorless colorless poisonous gas, a silent killer in all aspects.

Comment: Technician with B said there is some special chemical in the gas for being able to smell CO. just like the gas smell from gas oven...Do you know if it true?

Comment: I wouldn't trust it

Comment: You should also have at least one CO detector in your house, which will alert you to any CO. In many places, this is required by law if you have a fuel-burning appliance and/or an attached garage. Usually this should be adjacent to any bedrooms.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

There is a chemical added to natural gas ([ethyl mercaptan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanethiol)) so you can smell leaks. However, this chemical burns, otherwise you would smell it when using a gas stove -- so it ***will not*** warn you of a leak after combustion, which is where the Carbon Monoxide (CO) hazard exists.

You should probably inform company B, and your home warranty company, that their technician seems to be giving advice that could get someone killed and get one or both of these companies sued.

This doesn't necessarily mean company A was correct about there being a crack, or that company B was wrong about there being a dirty flame sensor. I'd suggest getting Yet Another technician in there to check both... or simply assuming that both problems exist and having both fixed; at worst, one of them will be good preventative maintenance.